# how could i navigate the different screens based on their categories and return back to home screen

Tags: flutter, navigation, categories

// this is the horizontal list view page on tap the categories are then required to go to their own page. when one category is clicked it then shows all the pages for all the categories before landing at the home screen. how could i stop this from happening.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class HorizontalList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 100.0,
      child: ListView(

        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,        
        children: <Widget>[

        // containers for categories
           Category(
            image_location: 'lib/images/supreme_airmax_white.jpg',
            image_caption: 'shoes',
           ),

           Category(
            image_location: 'lib/images/cats/offwhite_belt_blackandyellow_accessories.jpg',
            image_caption: 'accessories',

          ), 

        ],

      ),

    );



  }
}

class Category extends StatelessWidget {
  final String image_location;
  final String image_caption;

  Category({this.image_location, this.image_caption});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
      child: InkWell(

       onTap: (){
        //pages for categories
       Category();Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/screen5');
       Category();Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/screen6');

       },
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve in your `onTap`? You're creating a new Category object and pushing `/screenX` multiple times?

Comment: on my tap i would like the container to open a new page. they are all meant to be individual

Comment: There's no need for creating a new `Category` object in your `onTap`, remove that. Keep only one `Navigator` push. Also, I'd recommend renaming your screens to the caption String, so that you can just use `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(image_caption)`. Alternatively, you can use an if statement to decide which page to go to etc.

Comment: thank you i have tried naming the screens based on their caption string then using the Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(image_caption). but it didnt work so how could i please use the  if statement

Comment: You'll have to do `pushNamed("/" + image_caption);` and also modify the path in the `main` file, where you declare path names to be the same as the one used in `pushNamed`

Comment: i have changed the screen names to the caption string and have done pushNamed("/ " + image_caption);  what should be done in the main file

Comment: Have a look at [Define the routes](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes#2-define-the-routes)

Comment: sorry i'm quite new to flutter this is my first project

Comment: i have read the define the routes documentation but it doesn't say more about complex routing with multiple containers. because i can route the pages but each container gets that same page.  thank you but your version of pushNamed("/" + image_caption); doesn't work

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Complex Routing with multiple containers" ? I don't understand why it doesnt work. You define the page routes like `"/shoes" : (Context) => ShoesPage();` as defined above, and in your `onTap` method put the line `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/" + image_caption);`

Comment: Sure, happy to help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order for this to work. the page must be named as the image_caption. in the main file where routes are defined. the page name should be declared like "/shoes" : (Context) => ShoesPage(); . In the onTap method Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/" + image_caption); can then work.